# How to check a virus code without infecting my machine?

Tags: security, virus

I need to write some simple virus code for my assignment submission. I need to check whether it works properly or not.. But if I run it, it will infect my machine. Then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it on a virtual machine? VMware/Oracle VM etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab your Windows virtual machine image from > [here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)
2. Install VirtualBox from > [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
3. Take a snapshot point to restore the system to its pre-infection state at anytime later
4. Run your malware for test
5. Restore your system state as needed to re-test your malware

Alternatively you can try **[Malwr](https://malwr.com/submission/)** - an online sandbox service for malware analysis

Comment: just make sure to disable networking in the vm, or if you do enable networking, that the network is not connected to anything that might be infected by the virus, like your host, for example.